# How to refresh iframe parent window only once?

Tags: iframe

How to refresh iframe parent window only once ?

```
window.top.location = "http://www.site.com";
```

results in endless refreshing.

Comment: You should add some context (what else is on your page, when is this javascript called etc)

Comment: I need to refresh parent page when div id="adSpaceAccount" loads on iframe.

Comment: var abc=document.getElementById("myiframe").document.getElementById("adSpaceAccount");   this should identiy the id within iframe right ? but what function to reload the page ?

Answer (score 0):

with a simple  `if`?

```
if ( window.top.location <> "http://www.site.com") { window.top.location = "http://www.site.com"; }
```